# Returning the rows from a table with a corresponding relation to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. `.expenses` and `.loans_expense`.

**.expense**

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**.loans_expense**

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| loan_id    | varchar(255)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| expense_id | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| amount     | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I wanted to happen is to return all rows of `.expenses` with a corresponding value from `.loans_expense` **EVEN IF** there is no record found in `.loans_expense`. However, whenever I add a `WHERE` query, `WHERE loans_expense.loan_id = 'some_id'`, it doesn't return a single row when a certain `loan_id` is not found in the `.loans_expense`.

I did a query, but fails to return, since again, a certain `loan_id` is not present

```
SELECT
    `loans_expense`.`id` AS `id`,
    `loans_expense`.`amount`,
    `expenses`.`title`
FROM
    `expenses`
LEFT JOIN `loans_expense` ON `loans_expense`.`expense_id` = `expenses`.`id`
WHERE
    `loans_expense`.`loan_id` = '2018-00001-00001'
GROUP BY
    `expenses`.`id`
```

I want it to return the following:

*When all with `loan_id` exist*

```
+------+------------------------+---------+
| id   | title                  | amount  |
+------+------------------------+---------+
|    1 | Rice / Food            | 2121.00 |
|    2 | Basic Bills(Total)     |   21.00 |
|    3 | Rent                   |   12.00 |
|    4 | Tuition                |  121.00 |
|    5 | Loan from Banks(Total) |   21.00 |
|    6 | Others(Total)          |  212.00 |
+------+------------------------+---------+
```

*When `loan_id` doesn't exist*

```
+------+------------------------+--------+
| id   | title                  | amount |
+------+------------------------+--------+
|    1 | Rice / Food            |        |
|    2 | Basic Bills(Total)     |        |
|    3 | Rent                   |        |
|    4 | Tuition                |        |
|    5 | Loan from Banks(Total) |        |
|    6 | Others(Total)          |        |
+------+------------------------+--------+
```

*When `loan_id` is present on some related records*

```
+------+------------------------+--------+
| id   | title                  | amount |
+------+------------------------+--------+
|    1 | Rice / Food            |        |
|    2 | Basic Bills(Total)     | 500.00 |
|    3 | Rent                   |        |
|    4 | Tuition                | 124.00 |
|    5 | Loan from Banks(Total) |        |
|    6 | Others(Total)          | 147.00 |
+------+------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: There is zero need for a GROUP BY clause in the query.

Comment: So how can I return all the values of `.expenses` even with a null `amount` that is related to `.loans_expense`

Comment: Gordon's answer should work for you.

Comment: `Your `WHERE` clause renders the join an inner join (because in outer-joined rows `loan_id` is null). Your `GROUP BY` clause picks arbitrary matches per expense. I think both these things are not desired. Are you looking for the `SUM(amount)` maybe?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The answer of Gordon solved my problem

Comment: @Aaron Alfonso: Okay, I'm glad to hear that. You said it didn't, so I tried to find a reason for this. So there can only be one record per `expense_id` + `loan_id` in `loans_expense`? That wasn't clear. Anyway, the condition placed in `WHERE` instead of `ON` alone doesn't explain why some rows still exists in the result but with one column empty. There is something you forgot to shpw us or which you obfuscated somehow in your sample.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The `WHERE` vs `ON` is exactly why some have and some don't; it's not `1:1` its `1:{0,1}`. Loan X does not have "Rice / Food", "Rent", or "Loan from Banks(Total)" expenses.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that you are showing *desired* results, not results from your query. Sorry. I guess when you said that Gordon's query didn't solve your problem, I was looking for any possible reason and oversaw this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
select e.*, l.amount
from expenses e left join
     loan_expenses le
     on le.expense_id = e.id and le.loan_id = '2018-00001-00001';
```

Note the condition for `loan_id` goes in the `on` clause, not a `where` clause.

Comment: Hi. I updated the post. I forgot to include current query. it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @AaronAlfonso . . . What does the query in your question have to do with this query?  They are quite different.

Comment: Again, I want to return all of `.expenses` even with a null `amount` that is related to `.loans_expense`.

Comment: @AaronAlfonso . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem. The recent error was with my code. All are good now